# Magento querying customers by eav option value

Tags: magento

We created custom customer attributes for date of birth:

```
dob_month, dob_day
```

They are frontend input type of select, and backend type of int. We are trying to get from customers following fields: `entity_id`, `dob`, and `store_id` (if possible one `dob` field, otherwise, separated into `dob_month` and `dob_day`).

Here's were we are struggling, we would like to filter by these option values. Example: dob_month = 05 and dob_day = 08

Everything we have tried we are either having to filter by the value stored in customer_entity_int for example: 1125 = eav_option_value of 05 or we are only able to retrieve the value stored in customer_entity_int.

I figure there must be a way. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the closest I have gotten:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('dob_month', 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('dob_day', 'left')
                ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('dob', "CONCAT({{dob_month}}, '-',{{dob_day}})", array(
                'dob_month', 'dob_day'
                ))
->addAttributeToFilter('dob_month', array(
    array('eq' => '1125')
))
/*->addAttributeToFilter('dob_day', array(
    array('eq' => '08')
))*/
->setPageSize(20)
->setCurPage(1);
```

Note: The PageSize and CurPage is just for testing to limit the results.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by being only able to filter either by dob_month or dob_day and not both of them.

What is the query that you get? do echo $collection->getSelect() to see what the final query is

Comment: We want to be able to filter by the `eav_option_value` not the `customer_entity_int `. In our example, the `customer_entity_int` value is 1125, which equals the `eav_option_value` of 05. We are trying to figure out a way to filter by the `eav_option_value` of 05.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants it, the best I got was to do it all via SQL:

```
SELECT e.entity_id,CONCAT(dob_month_eav.value, '-',dob_day.dob_day) as dob,e.store_id FROM customer_entity AS e
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int AS cv 
ON ( cv.attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute 
    WHERE entity_type_id = e.entity_type_id 
    AND attribute_code = 'dob_month'
    )
AND cv.entity_id = e.entity_id)
LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` as `dob_month_eav` ON dob_month_eav.option_id=cv.value 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT e.entity_id,dob_day_eav.value as dob_day,e.store_id FROM customer_entity AS e
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int AS cv 
ON ( cv.attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute 
    WHERE entity_type_id = e.entity_type_id 
    AND attribute_code = 'dob_day'
    )
AND cv.entity_id = e.entity_id)
LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` as `dob_day_eav` ON dob_day_eav.option_id=cv.value) as dob_day ON dob_day.entity_id=e.entity_id
WHERE dob_month_eav.store_id=0 AND dob_month_eav.value='05' AND dob_day='08'
```